# Trigger jobs without occupying workers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have designed our test jobs to some sort of "abstract" test jobs, that run according to a set of parameters. These jobs are triggered use "runner" jobs that simply trigger them with the correct parameters (mostly generated by matrix jobs).

When we run multiple "runners", that all they do is simply trigger the abstract jobs, they occupy much needed workers (especially when it is a matrix job, that creates multiple temporary "runner" jobs).

Is there a way to tell jenkins to not spend a worker on a job that only trigger other jobs, or trigger jobs within the same worker?

Comment: Do the "runners" continue running after triggering the other jobs? I have used a similar setup where the "runners" only actually run and take a worker for a split second.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you use to trigger the jobs

If you use **Trigger/call builds on other projects** action, it has an option to **Block until the triggered projects finish their builds**. If that is checked, the triggering parent job will remain running and waiting for the triggered job to finish (thus occupying at least 2 executors). However, if you keep that unchecked, it will launch the triggered job, and the triggering job will end soon after.

Answer (score 0):

I want my builds to wait until triggered jobs are completed, for reporting purposes and such (I don't want that logic in the triggered jobs due to their abstract nature).

What I decided to do, since the triggering jobs are very lightweight, I restricted them all to the master. I allocated a large number of workers to the master, since they won't do much work and they will simply manage the triggering of other jobs.